# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type in Twilio 9.1.0

Tags: android, twilio, android-sms

I'm trying to use Twilio api(9.1.0) to send sms but i'm getting an error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7
Process: au.com.thermalog, PID: 2004
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; in class Lorg/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes4.dex)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:123)
    at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:70)
    at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:45)
    at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.<init>(NetworkHttpClient.java:36)
    at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient$Builder.build(TwilioRestClient.java:143)
    at com.twilio.Twilio.buildRestClient(Twilio.java:202)
    at com.twilio.Twilio.getRestClient(Twilio.java:174)
    at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:40)
    at au.com.thermalog.service.SMSService.sendSMS(SMSService.java:41)
    at au.com.thermalog.service.EmailService.lambda$sendEmail$0$au-com-thermalog-service-EmailService(EmailService.java:121)
    at au.com.thermalog.service.EmailService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

How can I resolve it?

```
 Twilio.init();
    Message message = Message.creator(
                    new PhoneNumber("+234353"),
                    "want to use Alphanumeric Id",
                    "Your message")
            .create();
```

This is the code that I'm using.

**Solution:**

```
protected void sendSMS(String to, String sms) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACC_SID/SMS/Messages";
    String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(ACC_SID+":"+AUTH_TOKEN).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("From","MG4c4e29ab......") // Here you put your Alphanumeric Id HexCode
            .add("To", to)
            .add("Body", sms)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .header("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials)
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        Log.d(TAG, "sendSms: " + response.body().string());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "sendSms: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

add this dependency

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
```

If you want to secure your account details, then you can get help from the official documentation.

Comment: For your alphanumeric id, did you follow the [steps here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-for-Twilio-Programmable-SMS) to enable it? My guess is that it isn't enabled correctly. You can check to see if it is by looking for the `enabled` status in your General SMS settings.

Comment: Can you post the solution so others can see how you resolved it?